# How can I create maven app engine project to be deployed in cloud

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I want to create maven app engine project that to be deployed in cloud.When i created normal maven project and it is not deploying in cloud.How can i enable it to deploy in cloud or is there any maven app engine cloud project setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mvn appengine:update` maven command to deploy appengine project on cloud. See [Using Apache Maven and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) for step by step understanding on creating maven based appengine project.

Before deploying set pom.xml settings and appengine-web.xml with your appname and version.

For Standard example see [Appengine-maven](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven) application on git, here `eclipse-launch-profiles` has launch files `DevAppServer.launch` will start dev server on local system and `UpdateApplication.launch` will deploy application on cloud.